# How to create approve and disapprove functionality for customer in magento

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have 3 customer wholesaler, distributor, retailor , i want to create one functionality if admin approve all of these customer then it can be log in otherwise it can not log in, how can do it? Please help me

Comment: https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login this might be a good start. doesn't do all you want

Answer (score 0):

I put together this extension which let's you approve / disapprove customers

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerApprove

Although I'm unsure if you are saying you want this at customer group level. If so why would you want to toggle customer group access?

With my extension you can toggle access via customer grid so you could filter however you want and use mass action

Comment: If there is a General customer then they don't need to wait for account approval, i need only wholesaler, retailor, distributor customer's approval/disapproval functionality

Comment: You will need to modify what I've written to look at groups. You've got very specific requirements. I don't think you are going to find an extension which does this without some modifications.